# SQL query with two orWhere

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I need your help.

I have a problem with a sql query that I can't do.

I have two tables, `patients and user`, in the patients table I have the fields, `name,last name, personal_id, strikes` and in the `users` table I have a field called `status`. I clarify, `personal_id` is a code assigned by the company, different from the PK.

In system logic, a user can be 'disabled' for two reasons.

1.-The administrator put the user's status in `Inactive`
2.-The user has 3 strikes or more.

So the query I am trying to do is the following.

Given a `value`, return me all the users that match in `personal_id OR last name` AND WHAT ALSO
users are INACTIVE (`Either for reasons 1 or 2`)

```
$patients= DB::table('patiens')
    ->join('users','patiens.User_ID','=','users.id')
    ->where('users.status','=','Inactive')
    ->orwhere('patiens.strikes','>=',3)
    ->where('patiens.last_name','like','%'.$date.'%')
    ->orwhere('patiens.personal_id','like','%'.$date.'%')
    ->get();
```

basically I need my query to fulfill this:

```
 This...
 ->where('users.status','=','Inactive')
    ->orwhere('patiens.strikes','>=',3)

 AND ALSO 

 ->where('patiens.last_name','like','%'.$date.'%')
 ->orwhere('patiens.personal_id','like','%'.$date.'%')
```

Basically, which first extracts `All Inactive` and then in that list look for all matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the conditions within a callback:

```
$patients= DB::table('patiens')
    ->join('users','patiens.User_ID','=','users.id')
    ->where(function ($query) { 
           $query->where('users.status','=','Inactive')
              ->orwhere('patiens.strikes','>=',3);
    })->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
         $query->where('patiens.last_name','like','%'.$date.'%')
           ->orwhere('patiens.personal_id','like','%'.$date.'%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried, and it throws me an error that the variable $date is undefined, but `date` is the value that I send from the form and it arrives as a parameter. But I tested it by writing a `last_name` in the query and if it works. I just have that error with the variable...

Comment: @AldahirRuizValdez you need to use a `use` for the anonymous function to inherit that variable from the parent scope ... https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php example #3

Comment: HAHAHA what an idiot I am, I didn't realize it was an anonymous function. They even put it in the answer. Thank you very much for your help. He had been at this all day.